# Migrating from Oracle to SQL server. Dual table select query -> SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, migration

I am moving from Oracle into a sql server 2008.

I had some query for the dual table in my system,

SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate, 'DAY')-0,'YYYYMMDD') FROM DUAL

Since there is no Dual table in SQL server, how can i achieve the same result with getdate with convert on the SQL Server ?

I have also heard adding a dummy table for dual, but should that work for my query?

Comment: to add / subtract date use the Dateadd command so : SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),  DATEADD(DAY, –7, GETDATE(),112)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `convert()` and no `from` clause:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 121), '-', '')
```

or use 112:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), getdate(), 112)
```

Comment: emphasis on the NO FROM CLAUSE.  Handy piece of kit, that.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server `FROM TABLE` is optional but it could be still required in case of JOIN and other complex syntax with aliases, best way to create it.

```
Select 'x' C into dbo.Dual
(1 row affected)
```